# Extending Core Class Codeigniter - 500 Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my web app I'm extending the Codeigniter core using applicaiton/core/MY_controller as below:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

And in my controller I have:

```
class Dashboard extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        // Your own constructor code
    }
    public function index(){


    }
}
```

This work perfectly on my localhost, however on my production server it returns a 500 error with an error message of **"PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MY_Controller' not found..."**.

PHP version on localhost is 5.4.10 and on production is 5.4.15.

I'm using the latest version of Codeigniter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you enable `.htaccess` in your production server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're developing under Windows (which is case-insensitive) and deploying on a UNIX-based host (which is case-sensitive). Rename MY_controller.php to MY_Controller.php, with a capital C.